Installing network controller drivers
After my laptop (82EY IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05) froze I have rebooted it, but neither my bluetooth nor my wifi were working. After copy-pasting commands from stackoverflow (a classic :P) I've managed to get my bluetooth working again but in the process, I have deleted my network card drivers
lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256)
       memory:d1600000-d160ffff

Even though I have found the necessary drivers on github (https://github.com/juanro49/rtl88x2ce-dkms), all of the listed installation methods don't work for me.
Both installations via building and installing .deb result in attached error.
full error: https://pastebin.com/4jrSXq46
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.9.3-76060903-generic/Makefile:1925: /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2ce/35403/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.9.3-76060903-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:2296: modules] Error 2

I am somewhat new to linux so all of the help would be appreciated.
Also it is not a hardware issue, laptop is dual-booted and the network controller works fine on windows.

I have managed to fix the issue myself.
Go through this installation process https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 (at least this one doesn't break for me while building) and then to activate the driver type into your terminal:
sudo modprobe rtw_8822ce
